# Broadcast receiver didn't work when logout from pusher

Tags: laravel, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, pusher

i did implement a broadcast notification in my application with pusher. it is in live. it work good but the problem is when i logout from pusher or close the pusher window then the can't get the notification. if i again login into pusher then notification work.

in blade:

```
Echo.channel('NotificationChannel')
  .listen('NotificationEvent', (e) => {
      if( {{Auth::user()->id}} == e.to_doctor_notification.id){
        toastr.success('You have a new patient request.', e.to_doctor_notification.name, {timeOut: 50000, progressBar: true, positionClass: 'toast-bottom-left', closeButton: true, newestOnTop: true, extendedTimeOut: 100000})
      };
  });
```

In controller:

```
broadcast(new NotificationEvent($to_doctor_notification));
```

in NotificationEvent:

```
public function broadcastOn(){
    return new Channel('NotificationChannel');
}
```

In bootstrap.js:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'app-key',
    cluster: 'ap2',
    encrypted: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. I have too many javascript file included. that why it doesn't work.

i include the pusher link
[this is pusher link](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://js.pusher.com/4.4/pusher.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

Those are Notification received code in which page want to see the notificetion.

```
<script>
      var pusher = new Pusher('app-key', {
      cluster: 'ap2',
      forceTLS: true
     });

var channel = pusher.subscribe('NotificationChannel');
channel.bind('EchoEvent', function(e) {
  if( {{Auth::user()->id}} == e.to_doctor_notification.id){
    toastr.success('You have a new patient request.', e.to_doctor_notification.name, {timeOut: 50000, progressBar: true, positionClass: 'toast-bottom-left', closeButton: true, newestOnTop: true, extendedTimeOut: 100000})
  };
});
```